# In C++, after overloading operator, does the operator lose its old functionality?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Does an operator, when I overload it, lose its ability to operator for types it was defined for before, or does the new definition only apply when I call

```
cout << that_specific_class_type_variable
```

If I write `cout << that_specific_class_type_variabe->Left()` will it be overloaded function or normal cout statement?

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* tptr) 
    {
     if(tptr!=NULL)
     {
      operator<<(out,tptr->Left());
      out<<(*(tptr->Entry()));
      operator<<(out,t->Right());
     }
     return out;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It will only change the behaviour for the specific type it's overloaded for, in your case, `TreeNode *`. Existing versions of the operator will continue to function as normal.

For the recursive calls: It will use your new definition of the operator if `Left` and `Right` are of type `TreeNode *` (or pointer to a class derived from `TreeNode`). If they are of a different type, the default version of the operator will be used.

I suspect that `Entry()` returns an object of a type different from `TreeNode *`. In that case, the standard definition of `operator<<` will be applied to it.

Comment: if i want to normally cout member variable of that class. Will i simply write normal cout function?

Comment: It depends on the data types you apply it to. I guess `Left` and `Right` are also `TreeNode*`, in which case it will apply your `operator<<` recursively. But `Entry()` probably returns a different data type, in which case the standard `operator<<` will be applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Operator Overloading does not mean changing the function and behavior of that particular operator forever or for the built in data types.
It only facilitates you to perform operations on your user defined data types similar to the ones you do on integral types.

For example if you have two integer variables, you can assign one the value of the other like this.

```
int a = 5 ;
int b = 7 ;
b = a ;
```

Similarly you may also want your own data types to behave like that for efficieny and easy of use.

```
//Hypothetical class
myClass obj1 (5, "abc") ;
myClass obj2 (109, "xyz") ;
.........
......
obj2 = obj1 ;
```

As for the output, you overload `cout` with `<<` operator to output the data of your object like this.

```
cout << obj1 ;
```

If you want to output the variables inside your class of integral types, you can do that like this if they are public members.

```
cout << myVar << endl ;
```

or like this if they are private members.

```
cout << getmyVar() << endl ;
```